# When does Core Data save the managed object context by itself?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a OS X 10.9 only, non-document application.
When i do not call `-save:` explicitly on my managed object context, when does Core Data call `-save:` by itself?
Up to now, i have only found out, that it saves before quitting the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you checked "Core Data" when creating a new Xcode project, this should be found i your app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    [self saveContext];
}

#pragma mark - Core Data Saving support

- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

So when terminating the app it will explicitly call save.

The right answer is: The context will only be saved when you call `save:` on it. But with the xcode template this is set up for you.

---

The code above is for iOS, for Mac OS X it looks like

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender {
    // Save changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.

    if (!_managedObjectContext) {
        return NSTerminateNow;
    }

    if (![[self managedObjectContext] commitEditing]) {
        NSLog(@"%@:%@ unable to commit editing to terminate", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        return NSTerminateCancel;
    }

    if (![[self managedObjectContext] hasChanges]) {
        return NSTerminateNow;
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {

        // Customize this code block to include application-specific recovery steps.              
        BOOL result = [sender presentError:error];
        if (result) {
            return NSTerminateCancel;
        }

        NSString *question = NSLocalizedString(@"Could not save changes while quitting. Quit anyway?", @"Quit without saves error question message");
        NSString *info = NSLocalizedString(@"Quitting now will lose any changes you have made since the last successful save", @"Quit without saves error question info");
        NSString *quitButton = NSLocalizedString(@"Quit anyway", @"Quit anyway button title");
        NSString *cancelButton = NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel button title");
        NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
        [alert setMessageText:question];
        [alert setInformativeText:info];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:quitButton];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:cancelButton];

        NSInteger answer = [alert runModal];

        if (answer == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn) {
            return NSTerminateCancel;
        }
    }

    return NSTerminateNow;
}
```

There the `save:` method is called, too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a moc is saved by itself at all

Comment: "mom" is the managed object model, which is usually fixed. You probably meant "moc" == managed object context?

Comment: When I quit my Core Data application without saving and then restart, all the data is here, so it must have been saved? I also did override -didSave in some NSManagedObject subclasses and log when it’s called, and this get’s called whenever quitting the application.

Comment: @MartinW: Perhaps `save:` is called explicitly in one of the application delegate methods, e.g. in applicationWillTerminate?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... in iOS the answer is simple. It doesn't, ever. Due to the thread dependency of NSManagedObjectContext I'm tempted to say that this is the same for OSX.

It wouldn't ever make sense for an NSManagedObjectContext to save itself.

What happens if the user quits your app half way through creating an object and isn't finished creating it fully? Would it get saved in a half complete state?